# @ComponentScan not working in test with spring-boot-starter-test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, component-scan

I am attempting to test my `@Service` and `@Repository` classes in my project with spring-boot-starter-test and `@Autowired` is not working for the classes I'm testing.

Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HelloWorldConfiguration.class
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = HelloWorldRs.class)
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.me.sbworkshop", "com.me.sbworkshop.service"})
//@ConfigurationProperties("helloworld")
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ActiveProfiles("test")
// THIS CLASS IS IN src/test/java/ AND BUILDS INTO target/test-classes
public class HelloWorldTest {

    @Autowired
    HelloWorldMessageService helloWorldMessageService;

    public static final String EXPECTED = "je pense donc je suis-TESTING123";

    @Test
    public void testGetMessage() {
        String result = helloWorldMessageService.getMessage();
        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED, result);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties("helloworld")
// THIS CLASS IS IN /src/main/java AND BUILDS INTO target/classes
public class HelloWorldMessageService {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String  message) {
        this.message=message;
    }

}
```

The commented class annotations on the unit test represent the various things I've tried to get this working. The test and the project packages are in the same package paths and the `@ComponentScan` works fine from my entry point (`@RestController` class with main method). The service `@ComponentScan`'s and `@Autowire`'s fine in my `@RestController` class in the src/main/java side, but does not in the test. I am required to add it again as a `@Bean` in my `@Configuration` class in order for `@Autowired` to work. The class is otherwise in scope just fine and I can reference and instantiate it just fine from the test. The problem appears to be that `@ComponentScan` does not appear to correctly traverse multiple entries in my test runner classpath, in this case /target/test-classes and /target/classes.

The IDE I am using is IntelliJ IDEA 13.

**UPDATE** - here are HelloWorldRs and its config:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class HelloWorldRs {

    //    SPRING BOOT ENTRY POINT - main() method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldRs.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    HelloWorldMessageService helloWorldMessageService;

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return helloWorldMessageService.getMessage();
    }

}
```

...

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> map() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    // This bean was manually added as a workaround to the @ComponentScan problem
    @Bean
    public HelloWorldMessageService helloWorldMessageService() {
        return new HelloWorldMessageService();
    }

    // This bean was manually added as a workaround to the @ComponentScan problem
    @Bean
    public HelloWorldRs helloWorldRs() {
        return new HelloWorldRs();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `HelloWorlsRs` look like?

Comment: Your test case isn't a configuration, and all of those commented things are irrelevant on it.

Comment: see updated post for HelloWorldRs, etc.

Comment: What happened? Did you fix you problem? How?

Comment: From the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` I see that you are using spring-boot - which is certainly a good thing. Do you have a `@SpringBootApplication` in your project? Can you try to annotate your test as `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: `HelloWorldConfiguration` is not a `@SpringBootApplication` so spring Boot will not be used to start the context.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to use `@SpringBootApplication`? If not I would use it. Otherwise your main config class is missing `@Configuration`.

Comment: No, I see I'm missing that. This was an older post and as soon as I get a moment I'm going get the code setup and test it again and update this post. (I'm optimistic). A very boneheaded thing to miss but I'll own up to it if I need to!

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd recommend to use a newer `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` but that makes no difference, it is just shorter (and recommended).

Second, from the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` I see that you are using spring boot - which is certainly a good thing. There are some good reasons why *not* to use `@ComponentScan` directly. Can you try the following?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes=YourApplication_or_other_Configuration.class)
public class HelloWorldTest {
... etc.
```

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` was recognizing the bean but was facing issue at run time. Adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` helped bean instantiation issue, bean was in different package which I had to specify using `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will turn out to be the solution, but don't use the default package (i.e. don't put *.java in "src/main/java" directly), and definitely don't use a `@ComponentScan` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in the default package. You will end up killing your application on startup as it tries to scan everything on the classpath (including all the Spring libraries).

Comment: point taken - just trying to get the components to load therefore the attempt to load from src/main/java to make sure nothing was missed

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot 2.7.3, JUnit 5.8.2

If you want to have full control about the spring's configuration (and not rely on the hidden magic of auto configuration) I suggest to create an explicit configuration class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.package.to.scan" })
public class MySpringTestConfig
{
    // just for spring configuration annotations
}
```

and reference it in your test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MySpringTestConfig.class })
@ExtendWith({ SpringExtension.class })
class MySpringTest
{
    ...
}
```